# Hbase Table is not showing any versioning

Tags: hbase

I am using Cloudera Quick Start VM and running hbase on that. Here are my queries:

```
hbase(main):009:0> create 'test', 'cf'
0 row(s) in 0.4500 seconds

=> Hbase::Table - test
hbase(main):010:0> put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value3'
0 row(s) in 0.1950 seconds

hbase(main):011:0> put 'test', 'row3', 'cf:c', 'value4'
0 row(s) in 0.0580 seconds

hbase(main):012:0> scan 'test' 
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                         
 row3                                    column=cf:c, timestamp=1414148485533, value=value4                                                                  
1 row(s) in 0.0420 seconds

hbase(main):013:0> scan 'test', {VERSIONS => 3}
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                         
 row3                                    column=cf:c, timestamp=1414148485533, value=value4                                                                  
1 row(s) in 0.0370 seconds

hbase(main):014:0> get 'test', 'row3', {COLUMN => 'cf:c', VERSIONS => 3}
COLUMN                                   CELL                                                                                                                
 cf:c                                    timestamp=1414148485533, value=value4                                                                               
1 row(s) in 0.0230 seconds
```

It is supposed to show two versions of row3 but later value is overriding previous. I don't know why versions are not appearing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the HBase table, specify how many versions you want to store.

In your case, you can do:

`create 'test', {NAME => 'cf', VERSIONS => 3}`

Comment: hbase(main):008:0> scan 'test',{VERSIONS => 3}
ROW           COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                                       
 row1         column=cf:c, timestamp=1414512356779, value=val2                                                                                                  
 row1         column=cf:c, timestamp=1414512350121, value=val1                                                                                                  
1 row(s) in 0.0400 seconds

Comment: If you want to see how many versions your table is set to store, you can execute describe '[table name]' and you will see part of the response is  VERSIONS => '1' or whatever the table was created with.